# How can I introduce the notion of order in a point-set topology?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Suppose that I have a function that outputs the concatenation of its inputs $f(a,b)=a.b$ .This can be represented with a topological space $(X,\tau)$ where $X=\{a,b\}$ and $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$. However, the topology only describes that there exist an open set $\{a,b\}$ that comprises $a$ and $b$ (i.e. where $a\in X$ and $b\in X$) but doesn't describe the order within the concatenation $a.b$ (i.e. that $a$ comes before $b$). So, how can I change/modify/extend the topological space so that I can express that $a<_{a.b}b$.

SOLUTION - "Dana Scott - Outline of a Mathematical Theory of Computation" (1970) (pdf here: [https://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~kwang/520/readings/sco70.pdf](https://ropas.snu.ac.kr/%7Ekwang/520/readings/sco70.pdf))

Comment: You’ve got too many braces in several places.

Comment: Do you mean that there is something wrong?

Comment: Yes.  Your topology is not a topology on $X=\{a,b\}$, and your subsets aren't subsets.  You can say $\{a\} \subset \{a,b\}$, for instance.

Comment: As an example of what you've done wrong $\{b\}\subset \{\{a\},\{b\}\}$ should be $\{\{b\}\}\subset \{\{a\},\{b\}\}$

Comment: ok, thanks. I've edited my question

Comment: Assuming your set is totally ordered, you can use the Order Topology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology .

Comment: @PeteBabe in my case there is no order on $X$. $a$ comes before $b$ as a result of the application of the function $f$ but not in general. So, is there a way to express that the application of a function on some of the elements of $X$ "imposes" an order on the subset containing its inputs.

Comment: I don't understand what the codomain of $f$ is supposed to be.

Comment: Function do not have inputs and outputs because they are not computer programs.

Comment: @Randall the codomain should be the set of pairwise ordered elements of the domain. For example, $f:D\rightarrow C$, where $D=\{a,b\}$ and $C=\{(a,b),(b,a)\}$ such that $f(a,b)=(a,b)$ and $f(b,a)=(b,a)$.

Comment: $\{\emptyset, \{b\}, X\}$ is also a topology on $X$, and differentiates between $a$ and $b$.You are free to interpret that differentiation as meaning $a < b$. There isn't much else you can do topologically. $X$ only admits four topologies: the discrete and indiscrete, this one, and $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, X\}$

Comment: @65537 This is not right. Notice that the function $f$ that you are defining is in fact the identity on $X^2$; it takes two arguments, i.e. elements from $X^2$ (tuples) and it outputs the same two arguments as a tuple. In particular, your example here is from $C$ to $C$, not from $D$ to $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the function $f$ that you are defining has domain and codomain $X^2$ for $X = \{a,b\}$, otherwise we wouldn't be talking about a well-defined object; moreover, as I mention in the comments, note that the function $f : X^2 \to X^2$ as you've defined it is just the identity on $X^2$.

Having established this, here is a simple way of coding the "order of concatenation" given by $f$ topologically. In this example there are in fact $4$ possible ways of concatenating the only $2$ elements of $X$, each corresponding to the $4$ elements of $X^2$ (you haven't mentioned that the two arguments in $f$ must be distinct!); after pointing this out, we let $\pi_1, \pi_2 :X^2 \to X$ be the projection maps onto the first and second coordinate respectively and by setting $\tau = \{ \varnothing, \{a\}, X\}$ to be our topology on $X$ we have that

$$a <_{a.b} b \iff \{\pi_1(f(x,y))\} \text{ is open and }\{\pi_2(f(x,y))\} \text{ is closed}$$
$$b <_{b.a} a \iff \{\pi_1(f(x,y))\} \text{ is closed and }\{\pi_2(f(x,y))\} \text{ is open}$$
$$a =_{a.a} a \iff \{\pi_1(f(x,y))\} \text{ and }\{\pi_2(f(x,y))\} \text{ are open}$$
$$b =_{b.b} b \iff \{\pi_1(f(x,y))\} \text{ and }\{\pi_2(f(x,y))\} \text{ are closed}$$